# Alternative to "self" in calling methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

This may sound really noob, but i've spent an entire day wrestling with this problem and would appreciate some help.

You see i have a method which I call more than once inside gameplay. If I use `[self myMethod];` then it works for ONE time. And then when I call it again, the animation in the method doesn't commence anymore.

What I need is to replace "self" with an alternative that can be "alloc'ed" and "released" to make my animations work.

I've tried;

```
@implementation gameViewController


gameViewController *object = [[gameViewController alloc] init];

[object myMethod];
```

However the above substitute for self doesn't even call on the method. I don't know what I did wrong, it's suppose to work just like "self".

Is there something i missed? How do you make an object of the class to work just like "self" does?

Thanks so much.

Here is a more detailed look of my code;

[self explosionAnimations];

```
- (void) explosionAnimations
{


      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Yellow Explosion.png"];

      [bomb setImage:image];   

      [UIView beginAnimations:@"bomb1ExplosionIncrease" context:NULL];

      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

      bomb.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.4, 3.4);

      [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

The setImage works fine every time. But the animations stop working on the second call of the method. While in the console it logs "animation completed" with nothing happening to the  image.

This leads me to believe that somehow "self" believes that the animation was already done and will not bother to do it again. So I thought a new "alloc" might give it a kick awake.

Comment: Most likely you're approaching this the wrong way. You probably just need to reset something so calling the method (with self or otherwise) works the second time.

Comment: @Nick Or possibly the other way around. Maybe at the time when `[self myMethod]` is called some extra setup code was called that isn't called in the OP's code sample. Like being added to a view or something, if the controller isn't displayed anywhere obviously the animation won't show. (I'm not very familiar with ObjC or with what the OP is trying to do here so I'm not really sure if it at all makes sense to instantiate a controller then not connect it to something. Maybe the solution is not to create a new one but get a handle to the existing one.)

Comment: @Chester If you're trying to run an animation on the same controller you're doing so when using `self`, shouldn't you be trying to call `myMethod` on the same object instead of creating a new controller?

Comment: Yeah I've actually been calling myMethod with self and it gets called every time I do. But what happens is that the animation completes it's cycle without anything happening to the image. I'm experimenting right now and the only thing i haven't done yet is to replace "self" with something that I can alloc and release. So the caller of the method is "brand new" and there is no way the method can ignore it.

Comment: @millimoose Added more of the code to show you my method...

Comment: @ChesterCordero Although you're resetting the image property on bomb (which I'm assuming is an imageview), the transform is on bomb itself which is already at scale 3.4 when you do it a second time. Reset bomb to scale 1 when you reset the image.

Comment: If you are copying and pasting that code from some tutorial you found on the net, I'd leave that site alone. `beginAnimations` / `commitAnimations` have been discouraged in favour of the block based animation methods since iOS4

Answer (score 5):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with "self". The problem is that you set the transform in your animation, and then when you run it again, you're setting the same transform, so it does nothing. You need to reset the frame to the new frame and then set the transform back to the identity transform before you do the animation again. Also, you should be using block based animations. I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but this worked for me (if you have auto layout turned off).

```
- (void)explosionAnimations {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Yellow Explosion.png"];
    [self.bomb setImage:image];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.bomb.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.4, 3.4);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        CGRect newFrame = self.bomb.frame;
        self.bomb.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.bomb.frame = newFrame;
    }];
}
```

If you're doing this in an app with auto layout turned on (which it is by default), then I would not use a transform, but just resize the width and height of the image view by adjusting its height and width constraints. So, in this method, you should make IBOutlets to height and width constraints you make in IB, then change their constant values in an animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.heightCon.constant = self.heightCon.constant * 3.4;
        self.widthCon.constant = self.widthCon.constant * 3.4;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help rdelmar! I was just about to comment back that I have solved the problem too. It took me quite the deep think while eating lunch to come up with an answer. In my case I have made a "Daisy Chain" animation where after the 3.4 transformation I re-transform it back to 1.0. But I will look into your suggested code and incorporate that when I come into more trouble with my code. Thank you so much. Your solution is more professional than mine but I have to study block animations more. I only know basics in animation.